# Update in ASP.NET results in an exception: "must declare scalar variable"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqlexception

I am trying to update a certain record in my `Student` table, however the same exception keeps popping up as such:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@sid"

Please do give any suggestions as I can't seem to find any error with my code.

This is the code for my update query:

```
if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    conn.Open();

    String sid = txtSearch.Text;

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Student] SET [Password] = @pass, [StudentName] = @studName, [Email] = @email, [PhoneNumber] = @number, [Faculty] = @faculty, [Course] = @course WHERE [StudentID] = @sid", conn); 

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studName", txtStudentName.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", txtPhoneNum.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faculty", ddlFaculty.SelectedValue);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", ddlCourse.SelectedValue);

    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    Response.Write("<script>alert('Record updated successfully!')</script>");
    conn.Close();

    Clear();
}
```

Comment: You haven't assigned value for @sid  here   WHERE [StudentID]=@sid

Comment: @Sergey hi, i am actually assigning a textbox value "txtSearch.Text" into sid, as shown in the statement right before the Update query. Is that not accurate too?

Comment: please see the answer below. You need to add something like cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid )

Comment: Just checked the answer below and it worked perfectly! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed out  @sid param

```
    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        conn.Open();

        String sid = txtSearch.Text;
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Student] SET [Password]=@pass
            , [StudentName]=@studName
            , [Email]=@email
            , [PhoneNumber]=@number
            , [Faculty]=@faculty
            , [Course]=@course 
        WHERE [StudentID]=@sid", conn); 
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studName", txtStudentName.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", txtPhoneNum.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faculty", ddlFaculty.SelectedValue);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", ddlCourse.SelectedValue);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isid", sid);     // <------
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        Response.Write("<script>alert('Record updated successfully!')</script>");
        conn.Close();

        Clear();
    }
```